# Change Validation Summary Text in MVC for a password validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, validationsummary

How do I change the default message on the validation summary when a password does not meet the requirements. The current message the appears is

> "Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9'). Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."

I want to change that text to something else.

Comment: the framework uses the data annotations on the password property of your view model to generate the error message. Start there.

Comment: I do have that, and it shows right above the password field. what i am trying to change is the error message in the validation summary. when using an HTML.ValidationSummary helper. I am unable to find that text above by doing a find all in the entire solution

Comment: The text you're looking for is the default `ErrorMessage` property of your `DataAnnotation`. You can custom it easily, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your example, you can use :

```
// ~YourModelFile.cs

[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z0-9]{6,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 6 characters long")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Interesting point is the `ErrorMessage` may be placed in a `Resources` files, so you can display it in multiple languages.
Plus, you do not have to write a custom `AddError` method anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. I hope it is the right way to do this. but here is my code. I commented out one line and replaced with the one right under it.

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                //ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "PASSWORDS MUST BE AT LEAST 6 CHARACTERS LONG, WITH AT LEAST ONE NUMBER, AND ONE NON LETTER OR DIGIT SUCH AS %, #, @, !, AND *. AN EXAMPLE: PASSWORD1$.");
            }
```

Comment: so this kinda worked.. however now it is using that same error message for different types of errors. I a m going to try what the AlexB suggested

Comment: Please feel free to accept one of the proposed answers if you solved your problem